# How do I compiling WSDL files?

Tags: php, soap, amadeus

I am using Amadeus web services which has 3 different WSDL files and I don't know how to compile them, can anyone please guide me through on how do I do this compilation part.

Comment: Have you asked the developers of that service?

Comment: That's what I am doing

Comment: This is SO, which is not related to them in any way. Questions about how to use a specific service/software should, in first hand, be directed to the company that built/manages that service/software. SO isn't a support helpdesk for companies services.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile" here? A WSDL file is just a description of some service, which can be used to configure a SOAP client.

Comment: By the way, if you were misled by Amadeus into thinking this was a way to reach them specifically, please point them to [this official help page on third-party support](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support). As Magnus Eriksson says, this site should only ever supplement a company's support desk, never replace it.

Comment: I expect that these files are not to be compiled as one (I've worked a lot with this companies WSDL files), they are meant to be used exclusively throughout the workflow of the solution. A bit more detail on your platform, and the functionality that these files apply too would possibly help you solve the problem a bit more

Comment: Hi Dave have you worked on the Amadeus’s Ancillary WSDLs? I really need someone’s help with this WSDLs.